# How to get the source code of a aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I want to get the main source of an aspx page.

How can i be able to know as to which and all links been created to get that site. When I right-click on the page, I get some Html page...but cant use it for compilation. Is ther some other way to approach this.? 
Help me out as i'm new to asp.net 4.0.

and yea, 1 more thing, I just need to get the UI design tags which produced the page.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you cannot see server side code in a browser. What do you mean by `UI design tags`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it... Unless you are local on the same machine OR Have ftp access onto the server. OR when IIS is not configured to server asp.net application.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have access to the server where the files are hosted you cannot see the source code.

ASP.NET is server side, so when you request the page the web server (IIS) will use the ASP.NET engine to do the processing on the server and then construct the `HTML`, which is the output you see in the browser.